# How can I generate events using the Poisson distribution in R?

Tags: simulation

How can I generate events using the Poisson distribution in R? The events could be the occurrence of floods in the next 1000 years at a given rate of occurrence per year.

Comment: Have you had a look at rpois()?

Comment: I will be *very* impressed the first time a thousand-year flood is attributed to somebody's `R` code.  Then we will *really* know we're in the Matrix. :-)

Comment: Do you want to generate the times of the individual events, or the total number of events in 1000 years, or some other quantity?

Comment: @ Glen_b I would want to generate the times of individual events

Answer (score 3):

The following gives you one inter-event time

```
 - log(runif(1)) / lambda
```

where `lambda` is the intensity of your Poisson process so the time-series of times of `n` events is obtained as:

```
cumsum(-log(runif(n))/lambda)
```

Comment: or use the built-in `cumsum(rexp(n,lambda))`

Comment: @BenBolker Wouldn't that be simply a uniform distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think so. `rexp(n,lambda)` generates n random exponential deviates with rate parameter lambda, the same as `-log(runif(n))/lambda`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
rate   <- 0.123456
period <- 1000
start  <- 2013.5
floods <- runif(rpois(1,period*rate), min=start, max=start+period)
```

since the dates are uniformly distributed within the time interval

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command rpois(n, 1000*lambda), where lambda is the average number of occurrences per year (and hence the occurrence in 1000 years should be 1000 times more), and n is the number of random values to return.

Comment: Wouldn't these be *counts* of floods during 1000 years, and not the *events* (or at least their times) themselves? What you need to make progress with this question is the relationship between the Poisson distribution for counts and the Exponential waiting time between them.

Comment: Thank you for the response Linda H,@ whuber I think its the count of events, I would need to have the times the events would occur instead.Thank you for the insights